# How Does One Do Block RAM Inference on Altera Cyclone 10 LP FPGA Boards in Verilog

Tags: fpga, intel-fpga, ram, fifo

I have tried to google for this a lot but I can't seem to find anything.

Comment: `interference` means `disruption` ... you may be using the wrong search term

Comment: Please provide a description of your problem and re open your post.

Answer (score 2):

You can infer block RAMs in three ways, depending on how much control you want.

1. Use the `altsyncram` IP core, which allows you to specify all settings for the RAM directly (less inference, more control)
2. Use the `ramstyle` attributes when you are declaring an array. How this is done depends on whether you are using [Verilog](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/programmable/quartushelp/17.0/hdl/vlog/vlog_file_dir_ram.htm) or [VHDL](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/programmable/quartushelp/17.0/hdl/vhdl/vhdl_file_dir_ram.htm).

   Verilog example (`"M9K"` should be correct for Cyclone 10 LP, though it might be `"M10k"`):

   ```
   (* ramstyle = "M9K" *) reg [0:7] my_ram[0:63];
   ```

   VHDL example:

   ```
    -- First, declare a signal that represents a RAM 
    type memory_t is array (0 to 63) of std_logic_vector(0 to 7);
    signal my_ram : memory_t;
    attribute ramstyle : string;
    attribute ramstyle of my_ram : signal is "M9K";
   ```
3. Rely entirely on the synthesis tool to guess:

   ```
   reg [0:7] my_ram[0:63]; //Hopefully it will pick a block ram, but might use MLAB if small enough.
   ```